# Can you set textview text within a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, textview, logcat

What I need it to have it once the app stops reciving text from the server saying that it is now disconected I need to set the button to say that it is disconnected, this is what I have right now (this is in a while loop I just didnt post all of the code)

```
Thread.sleep(10);
                        counter++;
                        if (counter >= 100)
                        {
                            Log.d("ClientActivity","send S");
                            counter = 0;
                            out.println("S");
                            A2MCString = in.readLine();
                            Log.d("ClientActivity","got " + A2MCString);
                            if (A2MCString == null) 
                                {
                                connected = false;
                                Log.d("ClientActivity","Closed1");
                                Connect.setText("Connect");
                                Log.d("ClientActivity","Closed2");
                                Connect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contect_button);
                                Log.d("ClientActivity","Closed3");
                                DeBug.setText("Disconnected from " + serverIpAddress);
                                Log.d("ClientActivity","Closed4");
                                }
```

the app crashes when I try to set connect to "Connect" the logCat error is "android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException" If you could help me it would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use runOnUiThread or a handler to make changes to UI from a thread.. I think this line is causing the error..

```
Connect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contect_button);
```

put it in runOnUiThread in your thread like this

```
       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() {

                        Connect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contect_button);
                    }
                });
```