# Force to execute specific part of the code first

Tags: java, android, textview

I got this code:

```
public void make_square(View v) {
TextView txt_wait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.square_txt);
txt_wait.setText("wait...");
try{
//rest of the code (scanning a bitmap for pixels)
```

"`make_square`" is an onClick event (at XML file).
When I click that I want to change a text (`txt_wait`)

Then after it is changed, he must execute the rest of the code.
But somehow it waits for the rest of the code, then when that code is done, then he changes the `txt_wait`

I also tried something like this (didn't work neither):

```
public void make_square(View v) {
    TextView txt_wait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.square_txt);
    txt_wait.setText("wait...");
    make_square2(v);
}
public void make_square2(View v){
    try{
    //rest of the code (scanning a bitmap for pixels)
    }
}
```

But also now, it first does `make_square2` before it changes the text.
Why or how can I fix this? That it changes the `txt_wait` first, then after it, then rest of the code?

Thanks already,
Bigflow

**Edit1:**

tried this:

```
public void make_square(final View v) {

    TextView txt_wait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.square_txt);
    txt_wait.setText("wait...");
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                make_square2(v);
            }
        }.start();

}

public void make_square2(View v){   
   try{
      //rest of the code
   }
}
```

and it gives my this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(17487): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
```

I also tried this:

```
    public void make_square(View v) {
        TextView txt_wait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.square_txt);
        txt_wait.setText("wait...");
        make_square2(v);    
}

public void make_square2(View v)
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
//rest of the code
}
        }.start();
```

Also this gives the exact same error.

I am not familiar with thread using, maybe I do something very bad.
Hope you can help me again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used AsyncTask to get this done, somehow the thread method wasn't working for me.

I used this tutorial:
http://www.android10.org/index.php/forums/43-view-layout-a-resource/908-tutorial-progressbar-running-in-asynctask

Thanks to AdilSoomro and JayeshPate.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a seperate thread for the code in make_square2 method.. then the text will be changed...and the remaining code will be running in a thread other than UI thread..which seems to be blocking the UI thread..

Comment: I tried, but didn't work. Could you take a look again, please? after **Edit1**

Comment: ok... i think in your code you are trying to change something in UI... and it can not be done from any other thread other than the mainb thread... so in you thread put the code which is changing the UI in runOnUiThread method

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean exactly, I am a beginner at android programming, can you explain it in a other way, or an other solution?

Comment: See my answer.for this .and put that runonUImethod inside your run() method of the thread...and instead of _Connect.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.contect_button);_ this line put your code which changes the userinterface...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374519/can-you-set-textview-text-within-a-thread/10374546#10374546

Comment: Ok, now I did the same as after **EDIT1**, but then with runOnUiThread methed.

It doesn't give an error, but now I got the same problem as before **EDIT1**, so it changes the text after, it has done the rest of the code.